# Facebook SDK, How do I check if a user has accepted my permissions?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, permissions

I've got to a point in my app where a user can login via the Facebook SDK. The app requests read and publish permissions. Is there a way to check if they have accepted the publish permissions before carrying on? The permission is `"publish_actions"`. I tried doing `Session.getPermissions();` but only the read permissions are listed there `(basic_info, user_birthday, user_friends)`.

It seems like there is no way to check if the user accepted my publish permission, is there a possible workaround to this?

The reason I need to check for this is because the permissions can be revoked by the user at any time from their profile, so I can't have them login then revoke the permissions, otherwise that would defeat the purpose of asking for it.

Would really appreciate some help, thank you. Hopefully it's possible and not a Facebook restriction (Although I can sort of see why if it was).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your app, you can use any valid user access token, and make a call to /me/permissions, and it will return a list of permissions that the user has granted your app.

For more docs, see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/permissions/

Comment: I see, ok. Thank you. My solution at the moment is to check the response from the checkin I am performing. If it fails it tells you it's because of the permissions not being there. Guess I can remove that now and do the check a lot earlier using this method.

Answer (score 5):

According to Facebook SDK v4+:

> To get the list of permissions associated with the current access
>   token, call:

```
AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken().getPermissions();
```

> To get the list of declined permissions, call:

```
AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken().getDeclinedPermissions();
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the Best way to check for permission:

**Facebook SDK 4.+ :**

```
if (AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken().getPermissions().contains("publish_actions")) { 
    //permission exists
}
```