# Android Facebook 4.0: Check permissions

Tags: android, facebook

Many things been [changed](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/upgrading-4.x) in Facebook 4.0.

How to check if user have permission in Facebook `4.x` api?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45002161/4724060

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Found it](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/android/permissions):

> People can grant only a subset of permissions that you ask for, except
>   for public profile, which is granted at login.
>
> People can also revoke permissions granted to your app in Facebook's
>   interface at any time after they have logged in. So your app should
>   regularly check which permissions have been granted. We provide
>   methods for you to check what permissions are currently granted to
>   your app.
>
> To get the list of permissions associated with the current access
>   token, call:

```
AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken().getPermissions()
```

Note that `AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken()` can be null

Answer (score 0):

**After Successfull Login Call this method**

[image]

```
    new GraphRequest(
        AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
        "/{user-id}/permissions",
        null,
        HttpMethod.GET,
        new GraphRequest.Callback() {
            public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {
                /* handle the result */
            }
        }
    ).executeAsync();

================================================================
 new GraphRequest(
                AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
                "/744511125731315/permissions",
                null,
                HttpMethod.GET,
                new GraphRequest.Callback() {
                    public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {
                        CommonMethod.showAlert("PERMISSION_GRANTED Fb ---> " + response, MainActivity.this);
                    }
                }
        ).executeAsync();
============================================
```